# static const Member Value vs. Member enum : Which Method is Better & Why?

Tags: c++, class-design

If you want to associate some constant value with a class, here are two ways to accomplish the same goal:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static const size_t Life = 42;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    enum {Life = 42};
};
```

Syntactically and semantically they appear to be identical from the client's point of view:

```
size_t fooLife = Foo::Life;
size_t barLife = Bar::Life;
```

Is there any reason other than just pure style concerns why one would be preferable to another?

Comment: Nowadays, compared to `static const`, C++11's `static constexpr` is better as it enforces that the compiler must be able to resolve the value at compile time, which signals intent and might avoid mishaps. This also _might_ help with optimisation later, but I provide no warranty for this speculation!

Comment: @alfC ...and? i didn't say it wasn't, because i wasn't talking about `enum`s.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `enum` hack used to be necessary because many compilers didn't support in-place initialization of the value. Since this is no longer an issue, go for the other option. Modern compilers are also capable of optimizing this constant so that no storage space is required for it.

The only reason for not using the `static const` variant is if you want to *forbid* taking the address of the value: you can't take an address of an `enum` value while you can take the address of a constant (and this would prompt the compiler to reserve space for the value after all, but only *if* its address is really taken).

Additionally, the taking of the address will yield a link-time error unless the constant is explicitly *defined* as well. Notice that it can still be initialized at the site of declaration:

```
struct foo {
    static int const bar = 42; // Declaration, initialization.
};

int const foo::bar; // Definition.
```

Comment: Actually - your compiler shouldn't allocate any storage space for the constant.  The standard explicitly states that only if the object is "used", ie. it's address needed, is the definition for the object required.  And then the developer has to provide a definition explicitly!

Comment: If you take the address of a "static const" but don't define it, then it should result in a linker error.

Comment: Richard, you're mixing intialization with definition here; you can well initialize the constant inline and define it separately. But you're right, I need to clarify my posting.

Comment: Using your example with VS2010, the linker complains that foo::bar has a duplicate definition (even if I add code that explicitly takes the address of foo:bar). Is that a compiler bug? Does it make a difference that foo is part of a static library?

Comment: @Adrian Simple, you are probably defining the constant in the header and use it in several compilation units. You cannot do that, for the usual reasons of the One Definition Rule. You need to define the constant in the implementation file instead of the header.

Comment: Older Apple `ld`'s may need the `enum` to avoid linker errors like *Undefined symbols: `<class>::<CONSTANT>$non_lazy_ptr`*. Also see [OS X 10.5 and Missing symbols for FixedKeyLength<params>::KEYLENGTH](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/255). I spent a day trying to get the `static const` to work; while the `enum` worked immediately.

Comment: @jww Is this really just an issue on older compilers? The code in question simply had a bug: it was trying to externally reference an undefined (and hence unexported) symbol. The correct fix would have been to define (rather than *use*, [as suggested](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/255#issuecomment-244839274)) the symbol. So the upshot is: if you want to make a symbol definition visible, you … uh, need to *define* it. See the last paragraph + code of my answer.

Comment: *"Is this really just an issue on older compilers..."* - It was limited to older Apple `ld`'s. As far as I know, the symbol was defined along with `MIN_KEYLENGTH`, `MAX_KEYLENGTH`, etc. No other compilers or linkers had trouble with it, and I tested back to VS2002 on Windows XP and GCC3 on Fedora 1. The comment you referenced did ***not*** work (it was my first try to clear it). Checkout some of the problems associated with that `non_lazy_ptr` symbol decoration.

Comment: @jww That's my point: the attempt didn't work, but defining the symbol should work. I'm puzzled that the original code works on other linkers. There simply is no symbol defined so it cannot be exported.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - *"See the last paragraph + code of my answer...."* - Oh, my bad. I see what you mean. Let me try that once I finish this round of testing. So I am clear... Is it safe to place the code/definition in a CPP file rather than an H file?

Comment: @jww Yes, the definition must go into the cpp file, otherwise you'll get duplicate definitions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Got it, thanks. That's what I thought. I'm not sure where/when I made the leap an explicit instantiation creates the definitions, too. Maybe I was getting lucky and took it for granted; and then ran into a conforming compiler where the assumptions did not hold. I'll have to think about that for a while....

Comment: Thanks again @KonradRudolph. You were right; I experienced the issue again during testing on Ubuntu 12.04 with GCC 4.6. I also observed it on CentOS 5 with GCC 4.1. But I'm also beginning to see a pattern: the issue surfaces under debug builds with `-g3 -O0`, and not release builds with `-g2 -O2`.

Answer (score 11):

They're not identical:

```
size_t *pLife1 = &Foo::Life;
size_t *pLife2 = &Bar::Life;
```

Comment: Essentially what I said, in less words. ;-)

Comment: Code sample should read (with added `const`s):

`const size_t *pLife1 = &Foo::Life;`

`const size_t *pLife2 = &Bar::Life;`

The first is ok, but the second yields a compiler error, since the identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants, and you cannot take the address of a constant.

Answer (score 9):

One difference is that the enum defines a type that can be used as a method parameter, for example, to get better type checking.  Both are treated as compile time constants by the compiler, so they should generate identical code.

Answer (score 7):

`static const` values are treated as r-values just like `enum` in 99% of code you'll see.  Constant r-values never have memory generated for them.  The advantage `enum` constants is they can't become l-values in that other 1%.  The `static const` values are type safe and allow for floats, c-strings, etc.

The compiler will make `Foo::Life` an l-value if it has memory associated with it.  The usual way to do that is to take its address. e.g. `&Foo::Life;`

Here is a subtle example where GCC will use the address:

```
int foo = rand()? Foo::Life: Foo::Everthing;
```

The compiler generated code uses the addresses of `Life` and `Everything`.  Worse, this only produces a linker error about the missing addresses for `Foo::Life` and `Foo::Everything`.  This behavior is completely standard conforming, though obviously undesirable. There are other compiler specific ways that this can happen, and all standard conforming.

Once you have a conforming c++11 compiler the correct code will be

```
class Foo {
 public:
  constexpr size_t Life = 42;
};
```

This is guaranteed to always be an l-value and it's type-safe, the best of both worlds.

Comment: Did you mean "guaranteed to always be an _rvalue_"? That's a lot more likely than what you actually wrote, but it's still not guaranteed. A `constexpr` can be allocated storage if its address is taken, in which case it becomes equivalent to a `const` variable after initialisation. But sure, if you don't do that, then `constexpr` is storage-free and the optimal solution for various reasons.

Comment: `constexpr size_t Life = 42;` will cause a compile error. It needs to be static, too. That's according to Clang 3.8.

Comment: "Here is a subtle example where GCC will use the address" [doesn't apply with GCC 5.1](http://ideone.com/iNXUog). Even taking a reference to a non-`constexpr`, `static const` doesn't *actually* take an address unless you try to take the address of the reference. Not sure how other compilers handle this, but you made specific mention of GCC.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if needed, you can take the address of a static const Member Value.  You've have to declare a separate member variable of enum type to take the address of it.

Answer (score 5):

### Another third solution?

One subtle difference is that the enum must be defined in the header, and visible for all. When you are avoiding dependencies, this is a pain. For example, in a PImpl, adding an enum is somewhat counter-productive:

```
// MyPImpl.hpp

class MyImpl ;

class MyPimpl
{
   public :
      enum { Life = 42 } ;
   private :
      MyImpl * myImpl ;
}
```

Another **third solution** would be a variation on the "const static" alternative proposed in the question: Declaring the variable in the header, but defining it in the source:

```
// MyPImpl.hpp

class MyImpl ;

class MyPimpl
{
   public :
      static const int Life ;
   private :
      MyImpl * myImpl ;
}
```

.

```
// MyPImpl.cpp
const int MyPImpl::Life = 42 ;
```

Note that the value of MyPImpl::Life is hidden from the user of MyPImpl (who includes MyPImpl.hpp).

This will enable the MyPimpl author to change the value of "Life" as needed, without needing the MyPImpl user to recompile, as is the overall aim of the PImpl.