# C++ equivalent of #define for integers

Tags: c++, c++14

I am looking for a portable one line replacement for the `#define` in the following code. The replacement should hide the word `APPLE` in the namespace of the `Foo` object.

```
class Foo {
public:
#define APPLE 123
    Foo(int a) : a_(a) { }
};

 // elsewhere in another file
    Foo f(APPLE);
```

I tried to make this more C++ friendly this, and it worked using the Intel 2017 compiler:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static constexpr int APPLE = 123;
    Foo(int a) : a_(a) { }
};

// elsewhere

    Foo a(Foo::APPLE);
```

but it *does not work* with g++ ((GCC) 6.3.1 20170216), because it gives the error

```
undefined reference to Foo::APPLE
```

because it is probably trying to take a reference to `APPLE`.

I know I can "fix" the problem by creating definition in a *.cpp file of

```
constexpr int Foo::APPLE;
```

but that violates my ideal of having the `#define` be replaced by 1 line. My `Foo` class is header-file only, and now I would need a `cpp` file just for the definition of `Foo::APPLE`. I know I could also declare APPLE as a function (`static constexpr int APPLE() {return 123;}`) but that is a whole lot more typing in the declaration and at every point of use I need to call the function with `()`.

It seems easier just to use the `#define` and be done with it.  Non-static `const int` works fine, but `APPLE` is not usable as an argument to the constructor.  Maybe there is a good reason why this is impossible in C++.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [Undefined reference to static constexpr char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780). That question is related to a string and why the particular error message comes up. I am trying to avoid using static linkage all together (I acknowledge in my question that I am aware of how to do static linkage) and I want to do it a "better/cleaner" way, and I see from the Answers that the way that passes my criteria is to use `enum`.

Comment: Can you use C++17? C++17 has inline variables for this reason.

Comment: C style? `enum { APPLE = 123 };`

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Can't use C++17. Intel doesn't fully support it yet, and we need to use Intel compiler.

Comment: @melpomene Well, the enum worked. I've gotten to used to C++11 enum classes and was worried it would generate a warning due a type conflict (which we promote to errors). But it didn't create a warning.

Comment: @MarkLakata Then the enum is likely your best option unfortunately. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to static constexpr char\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [static const Member Value vs. Member enum : Which Method is Better & Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204983/608639) and [Why should I prefer static constexpr int in a class over enum for class-level integral constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35213098/608639)

Comment: `static constexpr int APPLE = 123;` requires a storage allocation and takes up space. You can take the address of `APPLE`. Use an `enum` instead. It is effectively a symbolic constant (but you can't take the address of it).

Answer (score 6):

You've already listed most alternatives in your question. You'll need consider which approach you want to take:

- Use inline variable which requires C++17 (your first attempt works implicitly in this standard)
- Define the static member in a source file, which you don't want to do
- Use an inline static member function instead, which you also don't want
- Use a namespace scoped constexpr variable instead of a member
- Use a member enum: `enum : int { APPLE = 123 };`
- Use the macro (don't pick this)

Comment: The `enum` method is the only one that works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the things mentioned already, there's also "poor man's inline variables":

```
static constexpr const int& APPLE = std::integral_constant<int, 123>::value;
```

You define a class template with a constant static data member whose value is what you want. You define that static data member out-of-line - but in the header, since it's a static data member of a class template. In this case, `std::integral_constant` does all that already, so you don't have to write your own.

Then, you define your actual static data member constant as a constexpr reference to that class template static data member; no out-of-line definition is needed because it is not possible to odr-use a reference initialized by a constant expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was not aware of the existence of `integral_constant` and the fact that template exists at all doesn't help me like C++ any more.  What problem was that intending to solve? (I understand it sort of solves this problem, but doesn't this put a huge burden on the optimizer to figure out that APPLE can be treated as a literal?

Comment: `integral_constant` is primarily used in template metaprogramming to encode a compile-time constant into a type. Using it here is convenient, but it's hardly its intended use. This is trivial constant propagation that the compiler should have little problems with.