# enum member vs static int member?

Tags: c++

When we implement `static int` member, I usually do like this

```
class A {
  public:
  static int a = 5;
};
```

But once I found the code below, that enables the same thing, I noticed that we can access the member through `A::a`. I prefer this because initialization before the main function is not needed as opposed to the static int

```
class A {
  public:
    enum { a = 5 };
};
```

Which one is better?
Is there any benefit of using `static int`??

Comment: What version of C++ can you use?  In C++17 `static int a = 5;` can be `inline static int a = 5;`

Comment: Don't declare class variables as public, it violates the rule of OOP.

Comment: Do you mean `static const int` or `static constexpr int`? Your current code would have `a` be mutable for the first example, whereas the second is constant.

Comment: The benefit of using `static int` is that it is a variable, and can vary when you set it to a different value.

Comment: Did you mean `static const int a`? You're comparing a variable and a constant... My personal preference: `constexpr int a = 5;`. Unscoped enums can trigger linter warnings recommending the use of scoped enum instead.

Comment: If you meant `static const` member, then please search; this has been asked and answered already many times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [static const Member Value vs. Member enum : Which Method is Better & Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204983/static-const-member-value-vs-member-enum-which-method-is-better-why)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any benefit of using static int?

Yes, in some situations, you need to change the value of the variables for all instances of a same class. That's not possible without the use of `static`.

Only one copy of static variables are created for all variable numbers of instances of an object & notice that they're only accessible by static member functions, i.e. if you change the value of a static variable somewhere in the class code, it'll be changed for each object of the specified class.

Comment: They meant any benefit _versus `enum`_. You can never change the value of an enumerator member (in their example, `A::a`), so this comparison is moot and seems irrelevant, like a comparison to non-static member variables instead of enums.